# Contains operation in hashmap key

Tags: java, hashmap

My hashmap contains one of entry as  `**key: its-site-of-origin-from-another-site@@NOUN** and  **value: its@@ADJ site-of-origin-from-another-site@@NOUN**`

i want to get the value of this key on the basis of only key part of `**"its-site-of-origin-from-another-site"**``

If hashmap contains key like 'its-site-of-origin-from-another-site' then it should be first pick 'its' and then 'site-of-origin-from-another-sit' only not the part after '@@'

Comment: You'll need a hashmap of hashmaps.

Comment: @RealSkeptic I am using only one hashmap in which while getting key value it should work like 'Contains' function or like like query in sql.

Comment: You can't change the way a hashmap works. You need to change the implementation - either linear scan (which makes your map as bad as an ArrayList) or a map of maps.

Comment: You could consider a `TreeMap` instead. You can kind of seek to a key value and then iterate sequentially from there.

Answer (score 0):

No. It would be a String so it will pick up whatever after "@@" as well. If you need value based on substring then you would have to iterate over the map like:

```
String value = map.get("its...");
if (value  != null) {
    //exact match for value
    //use it
} else {//or use map or map which will reduce your search time but increase complexity
    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        if (entry.getKey().startsWith("its...")) {
            //that's the value i needed.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Or alternatively the OP can create a `Map of Maps`

Answer (score 0):

You can consider using a [Patricia trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_tree). It's a data structure like a `TreeMap` where the key is a `String` and any type of value. It's kind of optimal for storage because common string prefix between keys are shared, but the property which is interesting for your use case is that you can search for specific *prefix* and get a sorted view of the map entries.

Following is an example with [Apache Common](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/trie/PatriciaTrie.html#prefixMap(K)) implementation.

```
import org.apache.commons.collections4.trie.PatriciaTrie;

public class TrieStuff {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Build a Trie with String values (keys are always strings...)
        PatriciaTrie<String> pat = new PatriciaTrie<>();

        // put some key/value stuff with common prefixes
        Random rnd = new Random();
        String[] prefix = {"foo", "bar", "foobar", "fiz", "buz", "fizbuz"};
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            int r = rnd.nextInt(6);
            String key = String.format("%s-%03d@@whatever", prefix[r], i);
            String value = String.format("%s@@ADJ %03d@@whatever", prefix[r], i);
            pat.put(key, value);
        }

        // Search for all entries whose keys start with "fiz"
        SortedMap<String, String> fiz = pat.prefixMap("fiz");
        fiz.entrySet().stream().forEach(e -> System.out.println(e));
    }
}
```

Prints all keys that start with "fiz" and sorted.

```
fiz-000@@whatever
fiz-002@@whatever
fiz-012@@whatever
fiz-024@@whatever
fiz-027@@whatever
fiz-033@@whatever
fiz-036@@whatever
fiz-037@@whatever
fiz-041@@whatever
fiz-045@@whatever
fiz-046@@whatever
fiz-047@@whatever
fizbuz-008@@whatever
fizbuz-011@@whatever
fizbuz-016@@whatever
fizbuz-021@@whatever
fizbuz-034@@whatever
fizbuz-038@@whatever
```